# Spring Boot session is not created in Azure

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

When we deploy our Spring Boot app to Azure Web App, the JSESSIONID cookie is not created, and it looks like there is no session at all.

This is our Spring Security session config:

```
private void setSessionManagement(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .enableSessionUrlRewriting(false)
                .sessionFixation()
                .migrateSession()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .invalidSessionStrategy(invalidSessionStrategy);
                //.maximumSessions(1)
                //.expiredSessionStrategy(expiredSessionStrategy);
    }
```

When we run in locally in Docker/IntelliJ, it is created. Besides this, I have already set the ARR affinity 'On' under the Configuration > General settings, but still no luck.

**Edit:**

Found the issue, we had to update Spring Boot: 2.3.5.RELEASE -> 2.5.4

Comment: Hi @Adam, Does that resolved your issue. if it is, please provide the steps so that it will be helpful for other community members.

Answer (score 0):

I am tried with latest Spring Boot version 2.5.4 I am not getting any issue. I can see the JSESSIONID cookie has created.

Seems like the some session issues has been fixed in the update. [Release v2.5.4 · spring-projects/spring-boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.5.4)

I hope your issue has fixed with latest version.